# kendo ui addClass('k-state-error') on second span

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have the following html code :

```
<span aria-activedescendant="categoria_option_selected" aria-busy="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-owns="categoria_listbox" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header k-state-error" style="width: 200px;">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" name="categoria" id="categoria" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="Affiti + Utilities">Affiti + Utilities</option>
        <option value="Stipendi + Contributi">Stipendi + Contributi</option>
        <option value="Consumo Mensile">Consumo Mensile</option>
        <option value="Voip">Voip</option>
        <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I want to add to the second span the class : `addClass('k-state-error')` and remove `removeClass('k-state-default')` based on select id.

I have tried :

`$('#categoria').closest('.k-state-default').removeClass('k-state-default').addClass('k-state-error');`

and :
`$('#categoria').parent('span').removeClass('k-state-default').addClass('k-state-error');`
this adds the class to the first span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of `$.closest` is not correct. It should be used to get any ancestor in the DOM (in your case `span.k-widget`). Once you get that element, you just nee to `$.find` the element that you want to manipulate.

Following code does the job:

```
$('#categoria')
    .closest('span.k-widget')
    .find('.k-state-default')
    .removeClass('k-state-default')
    .addClass('k-state-error');
```